# Pandas dataframe delete rows if the gap is more than 3 days

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, delete-row

So I have 2 pandas dataframe. One has all dates for a person (`df_all_days`) between given date range another has only active days for the person (`df_active_days`). I want to delete inactive rows from `df_all_days` only if the person is not active for more than 3 consecutive days. And delete only those dates that satisfy this condition, not any other active or inactive dates.

For example in below; in `df_all_days` delete all rows for 'DG-3465' do not delete inactive dates of 2/2 - 2/3 but delete inactive dates between 2/8-2/12.
Also, delete all between for 'TY-9456' 2/9-2/13

```
df_all_days
PersonID        Date 
AB-123      2/1/2016
AB-123      2/2/2016
AB-123      2/3/2016
AB-123      2/4/2016
AB-123      2/5/2016
AB-123      2/6/2016
AB-123      2/7/2016
AB-123      2/8/2016
AB-123      2/9/2016
AB-123      2/10/2016
AB-123      2/11/2016
AB-123      2/12/2016
AB-123      2/13/2016
DG-3465     2/1/2016
DG-3465     2/2/2016
DG-3465     2/3/2016
DG-3465     2/4/2016
DG-3465     2/5/2016
DG-3465     2/6/2016
DG-3465     2/7/2016
DG-3465     2/8/2016
DG-3465     2/9/2016
DG-3465     2/10/2016
DG-3465     2/11/2016
DG-3465     2/12/2016
DG-3465     2/13/2016
TY-9456     2/1/2016
TY-9456     2/2/2016
TY-9456     2/3/2016
TY-9456     2/4/2016
TY-9456     2/5/2016
TY-9456     2/6/2016
TY-9456     2/7/2016
TY-9456     2/8/2016
TY-9456     2/9/2016
TY-9456     2/10/2016
TY-9456     2/11/2016
TY-9456     2/12/2016
TY-9456     2/13/2016

df_active_days
PersonID        Date 
AB-123      2/1/2016
AB-123      2/2/2016
AB-123      2/3/2016
AB-123      2/7/2016
AB-123      2/8/2016
AB-123      2/9/2016
AB-123      2/10/2016
AB-123      2/11/2016
AB-123      2/12/2016
AB-123      2/13/2016
DG-3465     2/1/2016
DG-3465     2/4/2016
DG-3465     2/5/2016
DG-3465     2/6/2016
DG-3465     2/7/2016
DG-3465     2/13/2016
TY-9456     2/1/2016
TY-9456     2/2/2016
TY-9456     2/3/2016
TY-9456     2/4/2016
TY-9456     2/5/2016
TY-9456     2/6/2016
TY-9456     2/7/2016
TY-9456     2/8/2016
```

I tried merging both dfs and then use backfill for dates that were NaN. Then added a column with 1 in all rows. then the plan was to do a rolling sum if dates are same and then delete all rows were the sum is greater than 3. But this had 2 problems,

1. It won't delete first 2 inactive days
2. The rolling window for some reason won't work on dates.

Comment: Can you add what have you tried ?

Comment: @ChihebNexus added the info add the bottom.

Comment: @Psidom can you help me here?

Answer (score 0):

```
#merge two DFs and get a indicator for inactive days
merged = pd.merge(df_all_days,df_active_days,how='left',on=['PersonID','Date'],indicator=True)
indicators = merged._merge.tolist()

#check if the inactive days last for more than 2 days
candidate=[]
final=[]
for k,v in enumerate(indicators):
    if (v!='left_only'):
        if len(candidate)<3:
            candidate=[]
        else:
            final.extend(candidate)
        candidate=[]
    else:
        candidate.append(k)
if len(candidate)>2:
    final.extend(candidate) 
#remove rows where there are more than 2 consecutive inactive days.        
df_final = merged[~merged.index.isin(final)][['PersonID','Date']]


df_final
Out[863]: 
   PersonID       Date
0    AB-123 2016-02-01
1    AB-123 2016-02-02
2    AB-123 2016-02-03
6    AB-123 2016-02-07
7    AB-123 2016-02-08
8    AB-123 2016-02-09
9    AB-123 2016-02-10
10   AB-123 2016-02-11
11   AB-123 2016-02-12
12   AB-123 2016-02-13
13  DG-3465 2016-02-01
14  DG-3465 2016-02-02
15  DG-3465 2016-02-03
16  DG-3465 2016-02-04
17  DG-3465 2016-02-05
18  DG-3465 2016-02-06
19  DG-3465 2016-02-07
25  DG-3465 2016-02-13
26  TY-9456 2016-02-01
27  TY-9456 2016-02-02
28  TY-9456 2016-02-03
29  TY-9456 2016-02-04
30  TY-9456 2016-02-05
31  TY-9456 2016-02-06
32  TY-9456 2016-02-07
33  TY-9456 2016-02-08
```